# Replacint single or multiple space to %

Tags: c#

I have string like `"First   Last  Name"`
I want to replace empty spaces to % like

```
"First%Last%Name"
```

How to replace consecutive spaces to single %?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, " +", "%");
```

Comment: The OP asked for spaces, not whitespaces, so " " is exactly what he needs. What's a regex "keyword" anyway?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = string.Join("%",
    str.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```